# How to make a button functional when loaded into a row from local storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
//loops through all rows and cells and saves them into local storage as objects
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  var rows = document.getElementById('firsttable').tBodies[0].rows;
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
    localStorage.setItem(i, JSON.stringify({
      Item: rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML,
      filling1: rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML,
      filling2: rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML,
      filling3: rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML,
      Stock: rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML,
      min: rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML,
      sold: rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML,
      closeAcc: rows[i].cells[7].innerHTML,
      sell: rows[i].cells[8].innerHTML,
      dltButton: rows[i].cells[9].innerHTML
    }));
  };
};


//loads the objects into rows with the values in their cells
window.onload = function() {
  var r = 0,
    c = 0;
  //load the actual data from localstorage into html rows 
  for (x in localStorage) {
    var row = table.insertRow(r),
      obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x));
    for (i in obj) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(c);
      cell.innerHTML = obj[i];
      c += 1
    }
    r += 1;
    c = 0;
  }
};


//where the problem is
$(function() {
  $('table td').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "Sellbtn") {
      var sell = prompt("Enter the amount");
      for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i += 1) {}; 
      this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt(this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[4].innerHTML) - sell; //not working and no when put inside the for loop it doesn't work idk why
    } else if (e.target.id === "Deletebtn") {
      return false;
    } else {
      var ask = prompt("Input");
      $(this).html(ask);
    }
  });
});
```

So i insert a row and add the details to the cells and such then as explained in the snippet the first function saves available the rows and cells into a JSON stringified object in the localstorage when the user is closing the browser and then loads them up during onload the problem is with the buttons idk how to make them function after the onload(user closes and opens again). So imagine this you have your HTML table with several rows and their cells and each row has the two buttons(sell and delete) how do i make them function when the user opens up the application again? and btw the buttons are both dynamically added using createElement() when the row is originally added

Comment: Use delegated event handlers rather than binding click handlers to every cell. That way they'll automatically work for dynamically added rows.

Comment: Yes exactly and that's what i'm doing now but i get an error now(cannot read property "4" of undefined) because of this line:
this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt(this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[4].innerHTML) - sell; i tried putting it inside the for loop but didn't work

Comment: `this` will be the td element, so you've got one too many `.parentNode`s in there.

Comment: So what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try delegating the click event you have on your table rows since they're being created after the DOM loads:

```
$('table').on("click", "td", function(e) {
```

Comment: I think we're on the right track now but i get an error it tells me cannot read property "4" of undefined.
because of this line:
this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt(this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[4].innerHTML) - sell;